# Need more details about Continuous access evaluation of Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, identity

I came across a new release from the Azure about identity security as mentioned in the below docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-continuous-access-evaluation#example-flows

I would like to evaluate and integrate with my application.
Looking for more informations about the process. Any pointers/links/docs would be really appreciable.

Comment: [Rolling this feature out first for Teams and Outlook clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/whats-new#continuous-access-evaluation).Let me known which application you are mentioning

Answer (score 0):

Continuous Access Evaluation is a new security feature that enables near real-time enforcement of policies on relying  parties consuming Azure AD Access Tokens when events happen in Azure AD (such as user account deletion). Rolling this feature out first for Teams and Outlook clients. For more details, please refer this [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/moving-towards-real-time-policy-and-security-enforcement/ba-p/1276933) and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-continuous-access-evaluation).